# md-sidenav-container is not working in angular material 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have installed angular-material2 and this is the package.json entry

```
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
```

then in my app.module.ts imported

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
```

and @NgModule

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, MaterialModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I have created a component that shows side navigation bar using angular material 2. This is the html code

```
<md-sidenav-container>
    <md-sidenav mode="side" opened="true">
        <md-list-item>
            <button md-icon-button>
           <md-icon class="material-icons md-24 white-icon">dashboard</md-icon>
     </button>
        </md-list-item>
    </md-sidenav>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

All other compnents of angular material 2 is working fine. But when I place my `md-sidenav` inside `md-sidenav-container` there is no navigation bar on view. But when directly use `md-sidenav` without the container it works. But could be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set a `height` to the `md-sidenav-container`.

Comment: Alternatively, add a `fullscreen` attribute to `md-sidenav-container`.

Comment: even after couple of years... this answer saved me couple of hours.. Thanks @Emerson-Jair

Answer (score 0):

Update: the import is now outdated. It is now:

```
import { MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material';
```